# Regex pattern which allow a string having length at least 8, but it not allow length 16

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

My requirement is to create a regex pattern which allows a string having length of at least 8, and for the maximum, allow any length except 16.

I tried this `^.{8,}$`  for requirement at least 8 character, but I am confused how to update it so that it can allow any length minimum 8, but not 16.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: ^.{8,}$   I tried this for requirement at least 8 character But i am confused how to update it so that it can allow any length min 8 but not 16

Comment: <if 16 the the max-length: `^.{8,16}$` else `^(?!.{16}$).{8,}$` to match more than 8 but not 16

Comment: It can be more than 16, 16 is  unallowed

Comment: @SaakshiAggarwal Thank you for the supplementary information and the clarification. It’s always to edit the question and add such there so we have everything in one place.

Comment: Is there a technical reason it has to be a regex? This type of thing is possible with most regex implementations but usually far less readable and maintainable than, say, a `Predicate<String>`

Comment: You appear to be writing a password strength validator.  Please don't try to put all your rules in one regex.

Comment: Doesn't [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52814058/372239) work for you?

Answer (score 2):

This does the job:

```
^(?!.{16}$).{8,}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               : beginning of string
    (?!         : negative lookahead, zero-length assertion that makes sure we don't have
        .{16}   : 16 characters
        $       : end of string
    )           : end lookahead
    .{8,}       : any character, at least 8
$               : end of string
```